# How to initialize an object with given key names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

The way I usually do that,

```
var update = {};
update[name] = data;
update.resolved = true;
```

where, `name` is a variable.

I assume that's not the most efficient way of initialization, but it's not possible to use a variable in object notation initialization.

Other possible ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) (which is an ES6 feature, but given you tagged your question as such I assume that's not a problem):

```
var update = {
  [name]   : data,
  resolved : true,
};
```

Comment: I tagged that especially, cause assumed that ES6 should already support that, but haven't seen any proof yet. Thanks.